# How to split the sting into array in excel and match from the list of column values

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula, split

I am trying to perform matching of the one column values with the list of values using the formula

```
=OR(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C3, second!B3:B5)), TRUE, FALSE)
```

[image: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl0BJ.png]]

it display true value if the value of column match with the list of values from excel sheet2. 
i want to split the column value like microsoft adobe  into "microsoft" and "adobe" and if it fount any of them in on the other list then it should display true value if none of the word is match then it should display false.
sheet2 is as

[image]

Expected result is as

[image]

Please help me in this regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b")&"*",second!B:B,0)))
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode to enforce the array formula

[image]

Comment: this formula works for spaces, but if we have any special character like /  for example if we have cell values "microsoft/adobe" then this formula display false. how we can handle it.

Comment: use `SUBSTITUTE` to change the `/` to spaces.

Comment: when i use substitute to change / to space it work fine for "microsoft/adobe" but does not work for ""microsoft adobe". how to use it with space as well as /

Answer (score 1):

You could also try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(C3," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(" ",1,second!B$3:B4)," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))))<>0
```

As a backup to avoid possible false positives looking for substrings.